# How do I create a path of a donut pie with a certain angle and radie?

Tags: svg

So my goal is to create a path in svg representing a part of a donut pie. I've drawn an image to explain what area I would like to create in svg. Since this shape is not a "real shape" I'm having problem calculating the paths.
I know I need to have these kinds of parameters to figure it out:

- Outer radius
- Inner radius
- Start angle
- End angle

[image]

My end goal is to make something like a trivial pursuit board with svg objects.
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1UheWuRttL._AC_SL1500_.jpg

Comment: Use an SVG editor such as Inkscape to draw whatever you want.

Comment: If you don't want to draw, but calculate everything. Start with a ``viewBox="-100 -100 100 100"`` so your center is ``0,0`` Then apply all angle functions you can find; yes, it will take you some days doing research.

Answer (score 2):

## SVG gauge, radial progressbar

- Rotate usung CSS `rotate` your SVG's `<circle>` elements - to a start angle *`deg`*
- Set Circle's `stroke-dasharray` to the circumference (`px` value)
- Set Circle's `stroke-dashoffset` to the desired degrees *`deg`*
- Set the desired value by using CSS vars, i.e: `style="--value:30;`

Example:

```css
.svgGauge {
  
  /* Settings */
  --diameter: 100;
  --stroke-width: 16;
  --color-track: #eee;
  --color-thumb: #0bf;
  --rotate: 0; /* 0=east (clockwise) */
  /* End Settings */
  
  --PI: 3.14159265358979;
  --TAU: calc(var(--PI) * 2);
  --radius: calc((var(--diameter) - var(--stroke-width)) / 2);
  --circumference: calc(var(--radius) * var(--TAU));
  width: calc(var(--diameter) * 1px);
  height: calc(var(--diameter) * 1px);
}

.svgGauge-track,
.svgGauge-thumb {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: var(--color-track);
  stroke-width: var(--stroke-width, 5);
  stroke-linecap: butt; /* butt round square  */
  stroke-dasharray: var(--circumference) var(--circumference);
  cx: calc(var(--diameter) / 2);
  cy: calc(var(--diameter) / 2);
  r: var(--radius);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  rotate: calc(var(--rotate) * 1deg);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.4s;
}

.svgGauge-thumb {
  stroke: var(--color-thumb);
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(var(--circumference) - var(--value) / 360 * var(--circumference) );
}

.svgGauge text {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  font-size: calc(var(--radius) * 0.03 * 1rem);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svgGauge">
  <circle class="svgGauge-track"></circle>
  <circle class="svgGauge-thumb" style="--value:30; --rotate:  0; --color-thumb:#0bf;"></circle>
  <circle class="svgGauge-thumb" style="--value:30; --rotate: 30; --color-thumb:#0fb;"></circle>
  <circle class="svgGauge-thumb" style="--value:30; --rotate: 60; --color-thumb:#f0b;"></circle>
  <circle class="svgGauge-thumb" style="--value:30; --rotate: 90; --color-thumb:#fb0;"></circle>
  <circle class="svgGauge-thumb" style="--value:30; --rotate:120; --color-thumb:#b0f;"></circle>
  <circle class="svgGauge-thumb" style="--value:30; --rotate:150; --color-thumb:#bf0;"></circle>
  <circle class="svgGauge-thumb" style="--value:30; --rotate:180; --color-thumb:#fbf;"></circle>
</svg>

<svg class="svgGauge" style="--value:145;">
  <circle class="svgGauge-track"></circle>
  <circle class="svgGauge-thumb"></circle>
  <text class="svgGauge-text" x="50%" y="50%">145°</text>
</svg>

<svg class="svgGauge" style="--value:30; --rotate:204;">
  <circle class="svgGauge-track"></circle>
  <circle class="svgGauge-thumb"></circle>
  <text class="svgGauge-text" x="50%" y="50%">30°</text>
</svg>
```