Progress indicator with gradient
I'd like to create a progress indicator with a gradient fill in HTML/CSS, similar to the one shown below, but with a number displayed in the center:

I successfully created a monochrome half-circle using this tutorial and a full circle with a gradient using this post. Below, you can find the code for both examples.
My goal is to combine these approaches. The post I linked earlier demonstrates how to set different border thicknesses, but I haven't been able to adapt it to suit my needs. I suspect it may only work with fixed values like 25%/50%/75%, whereas I need to use completely dynamic values. Additionally, I want the chart's background to be transparent.
Is it possible to achieve this entirely with CSS, or should I consider using SVG or another approach?


body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #c084fc22 0%, #fb923c22  100%);
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
 }

.progress {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.progress--half {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 10px #fb923c;
  mask: linear-gradient(#000, #000) padding-box, conic-gradient(#000 50%, #ffffff22 0%) border-box;
}

.progress--gradient {
  position: relative
}

.progress--gradient::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(#fb923c, #c084fc, #818cf8, #c084fc, #fb923c);
  mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
 mask-composite: exclude;
}

.progress--half-gradient {
 /* ? */
}
<div class="progress progress--half">50%</div>
<div class="progress progress--gradient">50%</div>




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633363/can-i-apply-a-gradient-along-an-svg-path

Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75450184/383904 ?
